# Show Company name in breadcrumb bar instead of dataarea

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, breadcrumbs

I just want to show company name in the breadcrumb bar in ax2012.

Is it possible to show the name instead of dataAreaId ?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can hide a dataAreaId and show custom text in status bar

```
static void statusLineText(Args _args)
{
    str     companyName = CompanyInfo::find().Name;
    ;

    xUserInfo::statusLine_CustomText(true);
    infolog.writeCustomStatlineItem(companyName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also show up the company name in title bar.
Modify workspaceWindowCreated method in Info class:

```
void workspaceWindowCreated(int _hWnd)
{
    super(_hWnd);

    WinAPI::setWindowText(_hWnd, strFmt("%1 - %2", curext(), xDataArea::find(curext()).name));

}
```